# Google Drive: How do I synchronize large files manually?

Tags: sync, shared-folders, google-sync, google-backup-and-sync

I am doing my video editing work in two separate computers. I am synchronizing the project files between two computers by using my Google Drive account.

My project directory consist of small and large files. The small files (<10MB) are project files, scripts, images, sounds and other resource files. The large files (>1GB) are raw files and rendering outputs.

I want to synchronize the small files by using Google Drive as usual. But for the large files, I want to manually copy them by using a USB memory stick. Because it takes a lot of time for them to be uploaded/downloaded and I don't want to consume other peoples connection bandwidth in the process.

I don't want to store the large files outside of my Google Drive folder, because Google Drive makes me sure that the computers are indeed synchronized, and sometimes I make an exception and use the internet connection to synchronized the large files.

This is what I tried:

1. Start with two synchronized PCs.
2. Quit Google Drive on PC2.
3. Upload a large file on PC1.
4. Manually copy the file to PC2 to the exactly same location.
5. Start Google Drive on PC2.

**Expected:**
Google Drive understands that they are the same files, mark that file "synchronized" and doesn't consume any unnecessary bandwidth.
**What actually happens:**
Google Drive on PC2 tries to upload that large file.

Is there a way of achieving this expected outcome?

---

EDIT: At this very moment, it is uploading and downloading the same file (file size: 5,045,385,571 bytes) at the same time! Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you have a file already uploaded to Drive on PC2, but then import a 2nd identical copy of that file to Drive (from another *non-Drive* folder)? Does it immediately recognize the duplicate, or does it upload the same file again? (What you want is _technically_ possible in general – e.g. Dropbox used to work this way – but if the particular sync tool wasn't written to do it, then achieving it would require directly editing its local database to trick it into thinking it has the file...)

Comment: I'm slightly tempted to suggest Syncthing for the large files (if all you want is sync between computers and not necessarily a cloud service), as it's fully peer-to-peer and will use your local LAN network to sync if possible, as well as using content-based matching to pull only the data it doesn't already have. [The downside of course being that it _has_ no cloud storage whatsoever, so both computers have to be online at the same time and there's no support team to restore data in emergencies.]